# User Path in the Flurry SDK (iPhone App)

Tags: iphone, flurry

I do not understand the user path in Flurry event.
Is this the path which the user take when he navigate in the application or is this the path constructed with the event which I have created?

Other question :[FlurryAPI logAllPageViews:navController]; 
Is this instruction list to me all the path which the user take when the user navigate in the application?

Answer (score 1):

The -logAllPageViews is designed to give you feedback as to which direction your users take when using a navigationController within your app. You can retrieve this pathflow on the Flurry website.